# How can snap applications view the manual permissions they have been granted?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, snap

Is there a method for a Snap app to introspect its own permissions?

I've built an app that requires the *raw-usb* permission to flash firmware on microcontrollers. Without it, the app does not work and I would like to inform the user with a pop-up that they have to add the permissions. Is there a way that allows the app to explicitly check which permissions have been granted? I have not found any information in the meta folder of the snap app.

For the *password-manager-service* permission I currently check it via an error thrown by the password library.

Comment: You may raise your question probably better in the designated forum for snapcrafters, see [https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snapcrafters/23](https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/snapcrafters/23)

Answer (score 0):

The helpful people over at [forum.snapcraft.io](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-snap-applications-view-the-manual-permissions-they-have-been-granted/37570/2?u=moritz) gave me the answer:

```
snapctl is-connected raw-usb
```

To quickly test it out, run the following to open a terminal from the view of the running app.

```
snap run --shell <snap-name>
```

If you're writing a Python app, for example, use

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["snapctl", "is-connected", "raw-usb"])
if result.returncode == 1:
    print("raw-usb not connected")
```